How to convert only the first letter as uppercase?
So, I want to convert only the first letter using REGEX and then bypassing function to uppercase it.
However Typst return "expected string or content found dictionary"
This is the source:
#let text="oh this is it"
#text.replace(regex("^\w"), m=>upper(m))

and oh, If you have insight on custom function as a callback in Typst I would be happy as I really struggle to find good documentation on it.
thaks
I tried that code and I expect the first char to be upprcased but didnt work

I think @KenWhite is suggesting something like #let text = upper(text.first()) + text.slice(1) would be more efficient

I have my own scenario. This is easier in JS or PHP but in Typst is a whole new creature that lacks on its docs. I solved it already.  Of course my real source  and case will not this simple as I provide in the question.

that's fine but your question reads as though changing the first character is your main concern. it would have been clearer if you had used a more general regex and not even mentioned the "first character" part. Note that "How to convert only the first letter as uppercase?" does not even mention callback functions.

So, finally I can resolve this.
While Typst scripting looks like JS, the implementation detail is bit confusing as the docs missing this kind of detail.
This expression will return expected string or content found dictionary
#text.replace(regex("^\w"), m=>upper(m))
the problem lies at m=>upper(m). So, Typst treat the m matched captured as Dictionary rather than direct value being captured, while upper() expect its param to be string or content.
The fix is simple.

First , let's see the keys of the dicts via repr(m).
It will return
(start: 0, end: 1, text: "o", captures: ())
from there, we know that we have .text dictionary key so we got the string as the valid value for upper() function.
the fixed code will be upper(m.text)

full fixed code:
#let text="oh this is it"
#text.replace(regex("^\w"), m=>{
repr(m)
upper(m.text)
})

EDIT: you can also use the shorter version without repr in just one liner fx:
#text.replace(regex("^\w"), m=>upper(m))


passing count: 1 to replace would avoid scanning the tail of the string for a match that can't succeed there

Why not just #text.replace(regex("^\w"), m=>upper(m.text))?

your code is right nick. I'm using repr(m) just to see the Dictionary structure of m. I can't find this kind of info in the Typst's doc. Someone helped me by this insight on Github.
